# Ubuntu GNU/Linux AMD graphics card issue

Tags: debian, ubuntu, graphics, amd, fglrx

when I bought my dell laptop, it came with Ubuntu 12.04 lts, but I removed it and installed windows 8.1 (now 10) on uefi
my story is: whenever I install any debian/Ubuntu distro, I use the open-source ATI driver (btw my graphics cards are AMD Radeon HD 8850/R9 M200x and Intel HD Graphics 4400 I guess) which is well and all, but I want the fglrx/-updates.
so I install it and next boot I open amd catalyst control center and when I want to edit vsync value (tearing :'() it's greyed out and it tears like crazy and a lot of options are hidden and not enabled, like the switch for battery saving and max performance

Looked and searched everywhere for this issue/bug/whatever and I cant find the fix or help needed

ANY help would be appreciated..

Comment: I can not even work out what you did. You started with Ubuntu (I assume this worked), then Microsoft's Windows 8.1, then 10, you still have 10, and also Debian/Ubuntu (so that must be duel boot), and you can not get Debian/Ubuntu to work with the graphics card. Is this correct? If so that is the relevance of the Microsoft OSs to the question?

Comment: yes, I have win10 and when I dualboot win wih debinan/Ubuntu distros and install fglrx (my graphics card is new) amd catalyst control centre isn't working properly (it's missing features and settings)

Comment: but my Windows OS is working flawlessly, with graphics cards and everything

Answer (score 0):

My first two ideas are "mode-set" and firmware.

Easy one first. Do you have the proper mode setting when you boot up?

The harder part. Is this a Dell Inspiron 15r?
This seems to be a possible fix regarding xleep and performance.

http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2218653/dell-inspiron-15r-5537-amd-8850m-switchable-graphics-enduro-sleep-hibernate-fix.html

Comment: my laptop model is Dell Inspiron 3537 with Intel-i7 4500U

Comment: and I want the driver to work in a Linux-based OS